# How can I reduce the number of figures of a number?

Tags: c#, serialization, numbers, figures, reducing

Is there a way to reduce the number of figures of a number?

Example:

```
double d = 222222222222222224444444444444.0
```

I want to "serialize" it like `17[2]13[4]` for example.

The idea is to reduce the number of "chars" used by the number.

Comment: Yes, there is a way. Were you thinking of doing this in a shell, in some particular language, or on a Turing machine?

Comment: What would you like the output to be for `d = 123456` ?

Comment: @Beta I think to do this in C#

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin for d = 123456 I don't see how to reduce the numbers of figures so the output will be 123456 I think

Comment: I don't know C#. Do you know how to 1) convert the number to a string, and 2) iterate over the string?

Answer (score 1):

> double d = 222222222222222224444444444444.0

You can't have a double that big in the first place.

> I want to "serialize" it like 17[2]13[4] for example.
>   The idea is to reduce the number of "chars" used by the number.

A double only takes 8 bytes regardless of its value. There doesn't seem to be any actual point to this.

Comment: Well, you could store `17[2]13[4]` in a string. But agreed about there being no point.

Comment: As 'the idea is to reduce the number of "chars" used by the number' there certainly isn't.